# How to traverse through hasMany relationship in console?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

```
App.CardCategory = DS.Model.extend
  properties: DS.hasMany 'App.CardProperty'

App.CardProperty = DS.Model.extend
  symbol: DS.attr 'string'
  label: DS.attr 'string'
  popover: DS.attr 'string'
  unit: DS.attr 'string'

DS.RESTAdapter.configure 'plurals',
  card_property: 'card_properties'
```

I can get both `CardProperty` and `CardCategory` via App.XXX.find() / find(n) but can't traverse through this relationship in Chrome console.

This:

```
App.CardCategory.find(1).get('properties').objectAt(1)
```

returns `undefined' whereas:

```
App.CardCategory.find(1).get('properties')
```

returns:

```
Class {type: undefined, store: Class, _changesToSync: Ember.OrderedSet, owner: Class, name: "properties"…}
```

I had always problems with getting data in the console so that I'd like to know what is the definitive way to do this.

---

### Update

In response to comment.

`App.CardCategory.find(1).get('properties.length') returns`0`. The response to`/card_categories/1` is following:

```
{
  "card_category":{
    "contains_new_purchase_slider":false,
    "id":1,
    "name":"Balance Transfer Cards",
    "promo_card_id":3,
    "promo_panel_active":true,
    "promo_panel_card_teaser":"Maiores rerum quibusdam consectetur id culpa. Enim unde explicabo et quae",
    "promo_panel_description":"Fugiat optio sint dolores non ut qui eveniet.",
    "promo_panel_header":"Unde ut voluptates eos ea dolor rerum mollitia.",
    "property_ids":[
      4,
      2,
      5,
      16
    ],
    "slug":"balance-transfer-cards"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `App.CardCategory.find(1).get('properties.length')`? I'm guessing it's 0. It may be a problem with how you're loading the data into your store, and it's not recognizing the association. What is the JSON response for the CardCategory?

Comment: I'll update the answer if you don't mind - it's too long for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Some quick details, hasMany and belongsTo aren't materialized immediately after a find.

Try a couple of things just to see if this is the case.

```
App.CardProperty.find(); // load the properties first
var cc = App.CardCategory.find(1);
var props = cc.get('properties');
propsLength = props.get('length');
props.forEach(function(prop){
   console.log('prop exists here: ' + prop.get('label'));
}
```

If it is the case, you can always do

```
Ember.run.next({
   // they will be materialized at this point
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time!

Answer (score 1):

OK, finally I've figured it out. Firstly, `CardCategory` should have `cardProperties` key and the key in JSON should be named `card_property_ids`. I think I could't use `properties' because the model is named`App.CardProperty`. So unline other model fields, **relations should be named after the model name**. Here's the correct example:

```
App.CardCategory = DS.Model.extend
  cardProperties: DS.hasMany 'App.CardProperty'

App.CardProperty = DS.Model.extend
  symbol: DS.attr 'string'
  label: DS.attr 'string'
  popover: DS.attr 'string'
  unit: DS.attr 'string'

DS.RESTAdapter.configure 'plurals',
  card_property: 'card_properties'

{
  "card_category":{
    "contains_new_purchase_slider":false,
    "id":1,
    "name":"Balance Transfer Cards",
    "promo_card_id":3,
    "promo_panel_active":true,
    "promo_panel_card_teaser":"Maiores rerum quibusdam consectetur id culpa. Enim unde explicabo et quae",
    "promo_panel_description":"Fugiat optio sint dolores non ut qui eveniet.",
    "promo_panel_header":"Unde ut voluptates eos ea dolor rerum mollitia.",
    "card_property_ids":[
      4,
      2,
      5,
      16
    ],
    "slug":"balance-transfer-cards"
  }
}
```